# Removing all reaction from a specific message in a specific channel

Tags: discord.js

```
// remove reactions from sign up message
    command(client, 'noreactions', message => {
        client.channels.cache.get(channelBotTest).fetch(messageWSSignUp).reactions.removeAll().catch(error => 
            console.error('Failed to clear reactions: ', error)
        );
    })
```

Here is my code so far.
I'd like to be able to run a command in a private channel that will remove all reactions from a specific message in a specific channel.

Getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAll' of undefined

I'm not sure if I need to define the channel too?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`fetch()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of instantly returning the value. To get the message object from the promise you can use `.then()` callback or `await` keyword.

```js
command(client, 'noreactions', message => {
    client.channels.cache.get(channelBotTest).fetch(messageWSSignUp).then(fetchedMessage => {
        fetchedMessage.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => 
            console.error('Failed to clear reactions: ', error)
        )
    }).catch(err => console.log('failed to fetch the message'))
})
```

Comment: Thanks!
Does this work the same if the message is an embed? If not, how should I alter it?

Comment: As is, im getting 'Failed to fetch the message' on the console.